# Need to open a chrome extension from button click + HTML + JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Need to open chrome extension from html button click.

I tried to use `chrome.runtime` to open an extension but there is no use.

The program executes but the extension is not opening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script> 
        // This function will trigger the Chrome extension with the specified ID
        function runChromeExtension(extensionId) {
            console.log(extensionId)
            // Check if the extension is already installed 
            if (typeof (chrome) !== "undefined" && chrome.runtime) {
                // If the extension is installed, send a message to it
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, { action: "run" }, function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            } else {// If the extension is not installed, show an error message
                console.error("Chrome extension not found");
            }
        }</script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="runChromeExtension('anflghppebdhjipndogapfagemgnlblh')">Run Chrome Extension</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions or am doing anything wrong?

Kindly  Note: Security settings can be modified to run the above program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you own chrome extension then 
Add your website url in `externally_connectable` key in manifest.json

```
"externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["http://mywebsite.com/*"]
    },
```

If your domain not exist in any installed extension then 
chrome make `chrome.runtime` is `undefined`

Comment: the extension is owned by third party, let me check with the extension team then